# Replacing underscore with upper case letter in java string

Tags: java

I have a string string_function_test.I need to convert this string  into stringFunctionTest. How can i do this using java.

Comment: This is not a "give me teh codez" site.  You have to show some effort of your own. Please read the [faq] and [ask] for details.

Comment: I have found  the solution for this question, how am I supposed to post an answer when the question itself is closed ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public static String camelcasify(String in) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean capitalizeNext = false;
    for (char c : in.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == '_') {
            capitalizeNext = true;
        } else {
            if (capitalizeNext) {
                sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
                capitalizeNext = false;
            } else {
                sb.append(c);
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

That's a basic approach. What's missing: some special handling for malformed strings (if necessary)

Answer (score 6):

Using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com):

```
CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL, "string_function_test");
 // returns "stringFunctionTest"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("skasd_kjsdh_kas_jd");
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            if(s.charAt(i)=='_')
            {
                s.setCharAt(i,Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i+1)));
                s.deleteCharAt(i+1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s);
```

Note: This will throw an `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` if underscore comes at the end.

Comment: `deleteCharAt` sounds promising but keep in mind that it has to copy portions of the buffer on each call. There's a tradeoff between readability and performance.

Comment: Hmmm....System.arraycopy for every deleteCharAt. Instead I think I can just replace underscore and nextCharacter with the Capitalized version of the next character...

Comment: If we replace two chars by one we have to shrink the buffer again which will perform some internal copy operations too. `StringBuffer` internally uses an array..

Comment: Yup!..+1 to your answer..It makes sense to create a separate string depending upon the requirement....I would have created a new String instead of trying to manipulate the Input string itself...